# Angular 13 how to configure manually lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-dynamic-components

I've tried everything to find a solution online and did research for days now but I'm unable to understand Angulars current concept of lazy loading module / components WITHOUT the router.

My overall scenario:

In my case my Angular App is only loaded as a part of a bigger page. I have placeholder distributed on that page like `<div id="first-comp-container">`. Now when my App is loaded I want to lazy load modules/libraries. Some of the modules need some sort of configuration. Once a module is loaded I want to create a component from that package and render it inside one off the placeholder.

My dynamic components have inputs and output events.I'll split up my scenario in a few seperate questions.

Problem  for this question:
I know I can lazy load a module in Angular 13 this way without router

```
const { MappingModule } = await import('@hwrm/mapping');
const mapModuleRef =  createNgModuleRef(MappingModule);
```

But first of how can I pass a provider like a InjectionToken to that lazy module in a form that it remains lazy?
Is there any way to pass a configuration to a lazy module like ModuleWithProviders forRoot()?

Comment: Lazy loading means that a part of the application is only loaded as soon as needed. To me it totally makes sense to make the decision, whether to lazy load a module, based on routing. But to be honest, your scenario doesn't sound like lazy loading to me. Sounds more like you **always** want to load the modules. Why can't you import the modules / libraries needed in the application root module?

Comment: Hi @JSONDerulo, I wanted to seperate my bundles right from the beginning. That's why I moved the components to their own library but I agree, lazy loading is not necessary at this point because the content is loaded with the application startup anyway. But the app and bundles will grow, so there will be lazy loaded modules at some point. I'll only eager load initial visible content. Maybe I need to let the app grow some more.

Comment: So what is the point in adding lazy loading then? Your application will be split up in more separate bundles, but the amount of code being necessary to load initially and the time of loading will stay the same or even increase. Splitting up also means doing multiple separate requests, which will create new problems like, what happens if one of the requests fail?

Comment: To sum up: Lazy Loading + routing totally makes sense, IMHO "lazy loading" of initial bundles doesn't make sense.

Comment: No it's not that easy in my scenario. I described it, classic router is not applicable because I don't have a classic app with routing. This questipn was explicit not about routing and routing is not the only case for lazy loading. Maybe my first module get's eagerly loaded but at some later point I load another module on button-click when a special form or anything is needed. So thanks again for your comment but it's not an answer for the general question itself.

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of `createNgModuleRef` method is an `Injector`, so you can pass either an existing injector with defined providers or use the static method `Injector.create` to create a new injector, passing in providers, like so:

```
Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: `InjectionToken`, useValue: {}] });
```

Obviously you can provide any sort of `StaticProvider` here, `InjectionToken` is just a placeholder name.

So a more complete example using your code might be:

```
const { MappingModule } = await import('@hwrm/mapping');
const providers = [{ provide: SOME_CONFIG, useValue: { foo: 'bar' } }];
const injector = Injector.create({ providers });
const mapModuleRef =  createNgModuleRef(MappingModule, injector);
```